# if a function accepts two arrays and that function will iterate each array one time is in O(n)

Tags: big-o, computer-science

If a function accepts two arrays and that function will iterate each array one time is in O(n)

```
a = [2 elements] // can be any length
b = [1000000 elements] // can be any length

function(a,b){
// NOT nested
  loop a  // O(n)
  loop b // O(n)
}
```

Is this `O(n+n)` but we simplify to `O(n)`?

Answer (score 1):

Time-complexity classes are a representation of how the time grows as n approaches infinity. Thus, you can multiply them by any finite constant k, and the time complexity will remain the same (because ultimately it won't matter for incredibly large values of n)

Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation
You can see the relevant section under "Multiplication by a constant"